# Display Image Using URL from GetElementByID

Tags: javascript, html, image, url, target

The code below is sending a URL of a image which I would like to display with the div ID being 'target', so far I can only display the actual URL address instead of the actual image.

```
            <script type='text/javascript'>
                function updateTarget( img ){
                    'use strict';
                    document.getElementById('target').innerHTML = img;
                }
            </script>
```

Target div

```
            <div id = 'target'> </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated as I am struggling to find any useful examples online.

Comment: You only parse the URl in the HTMl, you never actually generate an image `<img />`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this line:

```
document.getElementById('target').innerHtml = '<img src="' +img+'"/>';
```